# Postgresql issue: help needed

Tags: postgresql, postgis, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE populated_places
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geography(Point, 4326) USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326)
```

says:

> ```
> ERROR:  function st_transform(geography, integer) does not exist
> LINE 4:  geom TYPE geography(Point, 4326) USING ST_Transform(geom, 4...                                                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 89
> ```

Comment: All issues posted with the [tag:postgres] tag are "PostgreSQL issues". Don't repeat the obvious in the title. Also, *help is always needed*. Please use a descriptive title. And describe the problem in the body.

Answer (score 1):

There is no variant of [`st_transform()` in PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) that would take `geography`. All of them take `geometry`.

Applying that function to `geography` simply makes no sense.

Maybe you ran this `ALTER TABLE` command repeatedly by mistake? Because it would make sense on a `geom` column that's actually type `geometry`. Also, you might want to rename the column after converting it to `geography` ...

Comment: seems they are  the same thing in binary.  `select 'SRID=4326;POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)'::geography::text = 'SRID=4326;POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)'::geometry::text;` return true. ..